# After upgrading to PHP 7.4 Fabrik form pugin stop working on Joomla 3.10

Tags: database, forms, joomla, php-7.4

I'm trying to get a PHP plugin working again on Joomla 3.10 that worked before I switched providers.

I also upgraded from PHP 5.4 to PHP 7.4.33. The plugin must associate a photo file with a personal card. The path of a file obtained from `unirrit_jos2.unr_joomgallery` via an id is inserted in the `caduti` table of the `unirrit_caduti` db. The plugin works inside of a Fabrik module on Joomla.

```
$galleryId = (int)'{caduti___ID_JOOMGALLERY_raw}';
    if ($galleryId <> 0) {
        //$myDb = JFactory::getDbo();
        $myQuery = <<< EOT
            UPDATE unirrit_caduti.caduti
            SET foto_ok = CONCAT(
                "/images/joomgallery/originals/deceduti_sul_fronte_russo_3/",
                (SELECT imgfilename
                 FROM unirrit_jos2.unr_joomgallery
                 where id=$galleryId)
            ) WHERE id_joomgallery = $galleryId
        EOT;
        $myDb->setQuery($myQuery);
        $myDb->execute();
    }
    elseif ($galleryId == 0) {
        $myDb = JFactory::getDbo();
        $myQuery = <<< EOT
            UPDATE unirrit_caduti.caduti
            SET foto_ok = NULL
            WHERE id_joomgallery = $galleryId
        EOT;
        $myDb->setQuery($myQuery);
        $myDb->execute();
    }
```

I tried to check if there are functions eliminated or changed with the new versions of PHP and Joomla.
I.e. I have tried to change `JFactory::getDbo()` with `Factory::getDbo()`, but without success.

I am expecting to update column `FOTO:OK` on table `caduti` with the path of the photo from table `unr_joomgallery` on form submission.

Comment: Please ask all of your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.